# ST3 - Expand Selection to Word and Quick Find Next - Double Assignment of cmd + d on Mac OS in Sublime Text 3.1.1 (B3176)

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, selection

*Apologies in advance if this is the incorrect forum for this question - I am an absolute beginner when it comes to programming of any sort.*

It seems that the `Expand Selection to Word` (Menu > Selection > Expand Selection to Word) functionality in ST3 has been assigned the same keyboard shortcut as the `Quick Add Next` (Menu > Find > Quick Add Next).

However, **even if one clicks on these options manually** (*ie* without making use of the keyboard shortcuts), **the effect is the same**: clicking on "Expand Selection to Word" simply finds the next matching strong and adds it to the current selection.

So now I'm wondering if I've just fundamentally misunderstood the intended purpose, even though the language seems unambiguous.

1. **Could someone please confirm these functions should behave differently, and**
2. **If so, how can I fix the behaviour so that I can make use of the `expand selection to word` functionality?**

Thank you in advance for you time and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that indeed both of these items are the same thing, placed in two different places and bound to the same key. The reason for that is that the command does multiple things, depending on the situation that you use it in, which makes it fit into both places.

For what it's worth, the operation of this particular command is commonly a stumbling block for newer users because there's a bit of subtlety to what it does (which is outlined below).

For verification that this is the same command;

- Use `Preferences > Key Bindings` to open the key bindings window; in the left hand pane, search for `find_under_expand`; you see this particular key binding (on MacOS it uses `super` instead of `ctrl`) :

  ```
  { "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand" },
  ```
- Use `View Package File` from the Command Palette, then open `Default/Main.sublime-menu` and perform the same search; there are multiple hits for the same command in different menu items:

  ```
  { "command": "find_under_expand", "caption": "Expand Selection to Word" },

  { "command": "find_under_expand", "caption": "Quick Add Next" },
  ```

You can also open the console with `View > Show Console`, enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`, then trigger the commands and see in the console that the same command is being executed regardless of which of the key bindings or menu commands you use.

---

Cycling back to the top, the command `find_under_expand` is often a stumbling block for newer users to Sublime because it does different things depending on the situation. This makes it quite powerful and useful, but can catch you unaware initially.

Specifically, there are a couple of things that the command might do:

1. If there is ***at least one caret*** that has no selection, **and** all carets with no selection are inside of a word, selection at every "empty" caret is expanded to cover the word under that caret. Thus, this command works as `Expand Selection to Word` in the menu.
2. If ***all carets are not "empty"***, **and** all selections contain the same text, the command looks for the next occurrence of the selected text and adds it to the selection by adding a new caret there and selecting it. Thus, this command works as `Quick Add Next` as well.

For example, here's the content of the standard `lorem` snippet:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

If you put the caret in the first `dolor` on line 1 and hit the key, the text `dolor` will be selected. This is #1 triggering; the caret has no selection and is in a word, so the selection is expanded. Pressing the key a second time, the `dolor` in line 4 is added to the selection. This is #2 triggering; the next occurrence of the text is found and selected.

Now we can reset things by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> to go back to a single selection, and moving the cursor so that we're back to a single caret and no selected text.

Now put the caret in `dolor` and hit the key to select it again, as before. This time, use a <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> on the word `amet` to add a second caret at that location. Now we have two carets, one selecting the text `dolor` and one inside of `amet`. If you hit the key now, you get #1 happening; the `amet` is added to the selection, but no matter how many more times you press it, the `dolor` on line 4 is not added to the selection. The #2 item above only triggers when all of the selections contain the same text.

Reset again as above, and this time manually select the word `dolor` on line 1 by using <kbd>Shift</kbd> along with your arrow keys. Pressing the key now may give you a bit of a surprise; part of the word `dolore` on line 2 is selected and added to the selection. Pressing a third time selects the `dolor` on line 4, and one more press gives you part of `dolore` on line 5 as well.

So clearly, this command does both things; it will expand the selection at the cursor out to the current word, but it will also try to find other instances of the selected text and add them as well.

The part of this that often messes with people's heads is that last example. As we saw in the first case, when we let Sublime select the word for us with the key press, continued presses ensure that only that exact text is found and added. However if you manually select the text first, the command selects all instances of the text, even if it's not a whole word.

This is incredibly powerful because you can for example easily rename variables by  first expanding the selection to the variable name, then by selecting all instances and typing a new name. There's no worry that you might select partial variable names. However if you need to select partial words, that is available to you as well.