# Re-naming variables in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Working in Sublime Text 3, I’d like to re-name some variables in my code.

When I select a variable, all occurrences of it are highlighted. Importantly, Sublime Text is smart enough to only highlight the exact matches, not all occurrences of that string. So, while the cursor is on the variable named `i`, it is not highlighting the i in my variable `points` or in the keyword `in`. Yay!

If I try to re-name the variable `i` by using multiple selection (Cmd+D), though, it selects all the i’s including the wrong ones. Oh no!

As Sublime Text seems to be aware of the exact matches, how can I select all occurences of the variable, in order to re-name it?

Comment: Don't select the text before you press `ctrl+d`; if you put the cursor in a word or at the start of it and then press `ctrl+d`, you will select the word and further selections will select only the word. When you select text yourself first, the key selects all instances of what you selected under the assumption you knew what you wanted (because you manually selected it)

Comment: Now I understand. It’s a bit counter-intuitive, as you have to select the whole word to _highlight_ only the exact matches, but _not_ select the word so as to _select_ only the exact matches. Never mind. It you make this an answer I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that this particular key binding does different things depending on whether or not there is already text selected when you press the key, as outlined in [Double Assignment of cmd + d on Mac OS in Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858585/814803).

If the cursor is within or at the start of a word, pressing the key will select that text, and then future selections will only match that exact word and not parts thereof.

When text is selected first, the command will select the next instance of that text even if it's part of another word.

The command itself is actually a derivative of the find command (the command in question is actually `find_under_expand`). As such, if you press the key while the cursor is on the symbol you want to refactor, it will select, and all other whole word instances of that text will also highlight as well (assuming that you have that option turned on in the `Find` panel).

So, the general workflow might be to press `ctrl+d` to select the word and see what gets highlighted, both to see where other usages might me as well as to get the same context as using `find` would do.